# Attach event to window from popup

Tags: javascript, dom-events, webrtc

I am writing a library to working with socket.

In MyPeer.js file

```
var MyPeer = (function(){
    function MyPeer( opt ){
        var self = this;
        this.socket = new Socket(opt);
        this.socket.on('message', function(data) {
            self.emit('onmessage', data);
            if ( data.type == 'MYTYPE' ) {
                self.emit('myevent', data);
            }
        });
    }
    return MyPeer;
})();
```

In my page, I create a new `MyPeer` and listen event. It works fine.

```
var myPeer = new MyPeer();
myPeer.on('onmessage', function(data){
    console.log('in onmessage');//it works
});
myPeer.on('myevent', function(data){
    console.log('in myevent');//it works
});
```

In this page, I open a new popup by using `window.open` function. In popup, I access `myPeer` variable and listen event. Some event works well, some event does not work.

```
window.opener.myPeer.on('onmessage', function(data){
    console.log('in onmessage in popup');//it works
});
window.opener.myPeer.on('myevent', function(data){
    console.log('in myevent in popup');//it doesn't work
});
```

Could you please help me explain why `myevent` is not working and how can I achieve this?

Comment: The IIFE doesn't have a return statement so returns *undefined*, hence the value of the global *MyPeer* variable is *undefined*. Something is missing… the function declaration within the IIFE does not execute any code. Remove the IIFE and just declare *MyPeer* in the outer (global?) scope.

Comment: Thank you so much. I edited and it not works too.